# How to use modulo in if-statement to execute some functions?

Tags: python, if-statement, modulo

I have a simulation time, starting from zero and counting upwards. Then I have some if-statements, in which I set the speed of a motor to a specific value. I want to execute different stuff depending on the simulation time.

E.g.,

```
if simulation_time % 5000 <= 0:
    motorSpeed = actionList[choice1]
elif simulation_time % 10000 <= 0:
    motorSpeed = actionList[choice2]
elif simulation_time % 15000 <= 0:
    motorSpeed = actionList[choice3]
else:
    motorSpeed = dict(speedLeft=0, speedRight=0)
```

As seen above, my thought was, if the time is less than 5000 do according to choice1, if the time is less than 10000 do according to choice2, etc. However when the time exceeds these values and become larger than 15000 it will get stuck in the last else-statement. It will keep doing the stuff provided there. I don't want that to happen. Instead I want to go back to the first if-statement and do the job there and then to the second if-statement and so on. I know that I should use the modulo (%) operator in somehow, but I didn't manage to.

To summerize, I want to execute the first if statement for 5000 ms and the second if statement from 5000 to 10000 and the third from 10000 to 15000 and repeat. I can not reset the time. It is the time of the simulator and it should not be reset to zero.

Comment: Read the docs about the modulo operator, especially: "The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero)"

Comment: So you want to test if `simulation_time % 15000` is less than 5000, 10000, or greater...

Comment: To clarify, I want to run the first if statement for 5000ms, the second for 5000ms, and the third for 5000ms.  The first if-statement will run between simulation time = 0 to 5000. The second will run between simulation time = 5000 to 10000 and the third one from 10000 to 15000. So far so good. But the simulation time will keep incrementing. It will never stop, and I need to repeat these statements again with 5000ms between them.

Answer (score 0):

I might do:

```
motor_speed_cycle = (simulation_time // 5000) % 3
cycle_list = [actionList[choice] for choice in (choice1, choice2, choice3)]
motorSpeed = cycle_list[motor_speed_cycle]
```

- The first line sets `motor_speed_cycle` to a value from 0 to 2.  The `// 5000` breaks `simulation_time` into the increments of 5000 that you're interested in, and then `% 3` turns that into a cycle that goes from 0 to 2 and repeats.
- The second line creates a list with indices from 0 to 2 that correspond to the three choices in `actionList`.
- The third line sets `motorSpeed` to the appropriate `cycle_list` value per `motor_speed_cycle`.  No `if/elif` required.

Breaking down the math in that first line a bit further (where `s_t` is `simulation_time` abbreviated to make the columns line up better):

```
  s_t       s_t // 5000     (s_t // 5000) % 3
    0                0                    0
 5000                1                    1
10000                2                    2
15000                3                    0
20000                4                    1
25000                5                    2
30000                6                    0
```

Note that `s_t // 5000` will be the same for all `s_t` values prior to the next multiple of `5000` (the int division operator `//` drops the remainder).

If I didn't need any of these intermediate values for anything beyond determining `motorSpeed` I'd probably just do it as a single expression:

```
motorSpeed = [
    actionList[choice] for choice in (choice1, choice2, choice3)
][(simulation_time // 5000) % 3]
```

Ideally I'd have had the foresight to just make `actionList` a list of the three actions rather than a dict with keys `choice1`, `choice2`, `choice3`, and then instead of turning it into a list I could just do:

```
motorSpeed = actionList[(simulation_time // 5000) % 3]
```

Comment: I actually like this suggestion. However, would you please explain how to slice time and repeat it periodically?

Comment: I thought I did.  *`/ 5000` breaks simulation_time into the increments of 5000 that you're interested in, and then `% 3` turns that into a cycle that goes from 0 to 2 and repeats.*  Which part of that is confusing?

Comment: Ha, just realized I used `/` (floating division) instead of `//` (int division).  That's what happens when you don't have an MRE so you can't actually run the code.  :)  Fixed!  Also added a table showing how the math works with example values for time.

Comment: I noticed that too. Amazing work :)

Comment: I wonder what this would look like if we don't want to slice the time equally. Let's say, we run the first action for 5000ms and the second for 7000ms, and the third for 10000ms. What I am trying to ask, is if we have different time portions for different actions, this cannot be mathematically presented by modulo, or am I wrong?!

Comment: Slicing it differently just makes the mapping more difficult; it doesn't at all affect using modulo to make it loop.  You'd just divide by 1000 instead of 5000, loop modulo 15 instead of 3, and set up your `actionList` to have 15 indices that map to 3 different actions.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a different variable to track this cycle and reset it when the timer exceeds specific threshold

```
motor_speed_cycle = simulation_time

if motor_speed_cycle % 5000 <= 0:
    motorSpeed = actionList[choice1]
elif motor_speed_cycle % 10000 <= 0:
    motorSpeed = actionList[choice2]
elif motor_speed_cycle % 15000 <= 0:
    motorSpeed = actionList[choice3]
else:
    motorSpeed = dict(speedLeft=0, speedRight=0)
    motor_speed_cycle = int(simulation_time / 15000)
```